How to use Netty to deal with two different SSL Cipersuit?
I am trying to use netty to implement SSL connetions with two different Cipersuits(RSA and ECC), and the first connection is all right when handshake completes and messages are sent correctly. But when I re-start the client it will have following execption:
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:499)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:145)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:64)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:612)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1445)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1338)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1387)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    ... 17 more

Process finished with exit code 0


but the handshake complete as well at this. And I re-start the client again, there is no execption but the server can not receive the message.
I hope the server will handle two cipersuit connections at the same time and response the reqeust conrrectly.

I've resovled this question by another native Netty interface.
SslContextBuilder trustManager(TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory) 
SslContextBuilder keyManager(KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory) 

These two interfaces allows you to insert multiple cipher suits through .jks files to your clients or server while building the SslContext.Source code.
